# Cant reference project after adding references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to do some NUnit Testing but for some reason I cant reference another project withing the same project solution.  I already added the references and tried using the 'using' keyword but with no luck.  Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is your NUnit project is targeting the wrong .Net version. Check the properties of both projects and compare the Target framework Version.

Comment: @Filburt For my NUnit its .NET 4.5 and my SpreadsheetEngine its .NET Standard 2.0.  How do I change these to be the same?  Its not giving me the option to change to .NET 4.5 or .NET Standard 2.0 for each

Comment: [.NET Standard 2.0 requires .NET Framework 4.6.1.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the link, I tried matching the table with the .NET I'm using for both the projects and its still not giving me access to the other project.

Comment: Does the target project have classes in the namespace you expect? There's not enough here to give a full answer.

Comment: I've set my .NET Standard to 1.0 for my SpreasheetEngine Project and for my NUNIT .NET Framework to 4.5.  Still cant reference anything from my SpreadsheetEngine